# What does these images/emojis mean?

Tags: emoji

I am not sure what the below images represent. I am aware of the first 4 but not the others. Aprreciate your help!

```
☁️ ==cloud
 == tux/linux
 == docker
 ☸️==kubernetes
 
 ♨
 ⬡
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a technical question, at least not in the way you've phrased it. If there's a technical documentation context in which these emoji are used consistently and frequently, it might be answerable, otherwise it falls outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is:

== python
 == key

Answer (score 2):

```
☁️ ==cloud
 == tux/linux
 == docker
 ☸️==kubernetes
 
 ♨==java
 ⬡
```